# AD user still have access denied to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have added some users to a AD security group and I am adding that AD group to my SharePoint 2013 site. After a while i checked the username in SharePoint but the user still not exist in SharePoint 2013 for some users.

I do understand that current default WindowsTokenLifeTime is set to default to 10 hours, but some of users are not still not in SharePoint after 24 hours.

What i did next is modify WindowsTokenLifeTime to 2 hours but unfortunately it did not solve the issue.

I run the following command

```
$sts= Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 120)
$sts.Update()

iisreset
```

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: All newly added user not showed or only couple of from new? did you run the profile sync after that?

Comment: we have some of them not sync. We have sync run nightly. The user at least have access next day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Are you pointing towards User profile services ?

this service is not present in SharePoint foundation.

if you are not using foundation then try "iisreset /noforce" and "gpupdate /force" though.

Comment: Thanks Using Sharepoint server 2013. We do not use User Profile service. I have performed iisreset and gpudpdate but still not work

Comment: have you checked the authentication type ?

Comment: Try using Cache expiration:

$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig 
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-Timespan –Minutes 5) <- default 1 hour
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-Timespan –Minutes 2) <- default 10 mins
$sts.Update()

Comment: DId your issue got solved ?

Comment: Not really. some users still experience the issue